# My Galaxy y s5360 is not detecting the sd card?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-y

I am using the Galaxy Y (S5360) with Gingerbread.

A few days ago my mobile stopped detecting any charger or usb. After some time it started working again but it still wouldn't connect via usb to a PC so I can't access my SD card.

I have reset my mobile also but I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you card in working on your computer. If your card is detected on your computer without any messages then there must be something wrong with your mobile.

Else if your computer detects your sd card and gives you any message to scan/format before using it...then consider running scandisk on your card once your computer detects it...

Hope this helps...